# Unable to find any of pip2, pip to use. pip needs to be installed

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

im using ansible 2.9  from venv i created  using python 3.7 in AWS Linux
the remote hosts are using default python 2.7 and i can't upgrade it
I'm using boto3 and need to install it but first, i need pip to be installed on remote
and i try to invoke it but i keep getting :

```
fatal: [10.0.6.182]: FAILED! => changed=false
  invocation:
    module_args:
      chdir: null
      editable: false
      executable: null
      extra_args: null
      name:
      - pip
      requirements: null
      state: latest
      umask: null
      version: null
      virtualenv: null
      virtualenv_command: virtualenv
      virtualenv_python: null
      virtualenv_site_packages: false
  msg: Unable to find any of pip2, pip to use.  pip needs to be installed.
```

I'm using :

```
- name: Upgrade pip
  pip: name=pip state=latest
  tags:
    - packages

- name: Ensure botocore and boto3 modules are installed
  pip:
    name: [ "boto3", "botocore"]
    extra_args: "--user"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use yum to install python2-pip first, please have a try.
if you have further questions, please let me know.

```
- name: install python2-pip
  yum:
    name: python2-pip
    state: present
- name: Upgrade pip
  pip: name=pip state=latest
  tags:
    - packages

- name: Ensure botocore and boto3 modules are installed
  pip:
    name: [ "boto3", "botocore"]
    extra_args: "--user"
```

Comment: well this worked but i have to add  wheels to boto3 and i got 
Could not build wheels for botocore, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
adding [ "wheels", "boto3", "botocore"] not helped

Comment: I think there is a typo, it's wheel, not wheels, please have a try for adding [ "wheel", "boto3", "botocore"]